# Hide or encrypt ps1 credentials

Tags: encryption, smtp, hide, send

i'm having an issue with my ps1 script to send mails. The problem, I have to send this script to multiple users and I dont want them to read my smtp credentials from the mail sender, is there any way to encrypt or hide the password line only, and still can be executed?

```
$Username  = "test"
$EmailPassword = "jlkajdksajeqw"
$Attachment= "c:\validacion.zip" 
$EmailTo = ("seleccionestmk@gmail.com") 
$EmailFrom   = "seleccionestmk@telemercado.com.ar" 
$Subject = "Validacion BPC"
$Body= "Validacion realizada, dentro del archivo zip, se encuentran los datos necesarios para aprobar o denegar la validacion. Saludos"
$SMTPServer  = "mail.telemercado.com.ar"  
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) 
$Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $false
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you encrypt the sensitive values somehow then the receiver of the script needs the decryption key in order to read the sensitive values to run the script.

You could run some kind of obfuscation software over your script to make it harder for the receiver of the script to extract the sensitive values, but you can never prevent such an extraction.

The best way would be to re-engineer the system in such a way that giving the credentials to the users is not an issue. For example, scope the email account from which emails are sent in such a way that it is used only for this one use case and all the users that you give the script to are also supposed to use it as such. If you're using the email account for other things then move them to a different account with different credentials.

Another way would be to create a server endpoint which validates the personalized credentials of the users (you need to give each user their own credentials) that you gave the script to and stores the credentials for the email account only on the server. The server would need to validate the fields that they conform to the way this email account should be used.